# Number not display while incoming call

Tags: calls, screen

I have a Htc Desire SV Dual SIM mobile. Today when I got call then I surprised that it is not showing name or number on display.

I tried changing settings, changed the wallpaper but still this problem persist.

You can see in the below screenshot which I captured at the time of incoming call. Here only two button option is there **Decline and Accept**.

[image]